# What counts for a satellite deployment contract?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The contracts call for "a new unmanned probe that has an antenna and can generate power".

According to the sidebar, this launch vehicle counts in that regard:

[image: launch vehicle]

However, once I jettison the first stage, it no longer counts. I am legitimately confused at why this happens.

Could someone enlighten me as to why the first stage makes a difference, and how I could change the payload so that it qualifies?

Here is a picture of the deployed payload, albeit an older version:

[image: payload, older version w/ mk16 as nose cone]

Comment: Did you happen to put a command module on it?  Without it, it won't be considered a satellite, just debris.

Comment: @lI You can see the probe core on both screenshots.

Comment: [Related.](https://steamcommunity.com/app/220200/discussions/0/135510669602673350/)

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the contract screen? There might be some other requirements that you're not meeting.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen this is specifically about the first requirement in satellite contracts, but for the record the only other requirements were "get to this specific orbit" and "stay there for 10sec". I wasn't missing any science equipment if that's what you mean.

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: @Philipp no, I don't.

Comment: Is the root part in the upper stage? Otherwise it will count as 'debris' probably.

Comment: @SF. At the time of writing, I think the root part was the decoupler. I did eventually fix it when I set it to the reaction wheel, but it was still counting the upper stage as a "probe" on the map before.